# Filling missing hours in dataset - scala spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that has values for each user for every two hours of a given day. I am trying to explode out the hours to have a row for those other hours where a score was not given, and assign the score to that new row from either the previous or next row.

Example of what the data looks like in both scenarios:

[image: Current state]

User A starts tracking scores every two hours starting at hour 1 while user B starts tracking scores at hour 0.

I would like it to look this this:

[image: Desired transformation]

So because user A starts with hour 1, I want new value at hour 0 = value at hour 1, new value at hour 2 = value at hour 3,

and for user B who starts at hour 0, I want new value at hour 1 = value at hour 0, new value at hour 3 = value at hour 2, and so on.

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, data or anything that can be posted as a text. Edit your post using the proper format. Also share what you already tried and why is not working

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 2.4, you can use a combination of `sequence` and `explode` to generate missing values of your dataframe:

- first, you define upper and lower bound for each rows

  - lower bound is the previous hour if the `hour_utc` is odd, else it is the `hour_utc`
  - upper bound is the next hour if the `hour_utc` is even, else it is the `hour_utc`
- then, you create a sequence between lower and upper bound
- then, you explode the obtained sequence
- finally, you remove upper and lower bound columns

Translated as code, it gives you the following snippet:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, sequence, when}

val result = df.withColumn("lower_bound", when(col("hour_utc") % 2 === 1, col("hour_utc") - 1).otherwise(col("hour_utc")))
  .withColumn("upper_bound", when(col("hour_utc") % 2 === 1, col("hour_utc")).otherwise(col("hour_utc") + 1))
  .withColumn("hour_utc", explode(sequence(col("lower_bound"), col("upper_bound"))))
  .drop("upper_bound", "lower_bound")
```

With the following `df` dataframe:

```
+----+----------+--------+----+
|user|date_utc  |hour_utc|data|
+----+----------+--------+----+
|A   |2023-05-27|1       |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|3       |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|5       |1.4 |
|A   |2023-05-27|7       |1.5 |
|A   |2023-05-27|9       |1.1 |
|A   |2023-05-27|11      |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|13      |1.1 |
|A   |2023-05-27|15      |1.0 |
|A   |2023-05-27|17      |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|19      |1.6 |
|A   |2023-05-27|21      |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|23      |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|0       |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|2       |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|4       |1.4 |
|B   |2023-05-27|6       |1.5 |
|B   |2023-05-27|8       |1.1 |
|B   |2023-05-27|10      |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|12      |1.1 |
|B   |2023-05-27|14      |1.0 |
|B   |2023-05-27|16      |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|18      |1.6 |
|B   |2023-05-27|20      |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|22      |1.2 |
+----+----------+--------+----+
```

You get the following `result` dataframe:

```
+----+----------+--------+----+
|user|date_utc  |hour_utc|data|
+----+----------+--------+----+
|A   |2023-05-27|0       |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|1       |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|2       |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|3       |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|4       |1.4 |
|A   |2023-05-27|5       |1.4 |
|A   |2023-05-27|6       |1.5 |
|A   |2023-05-27|7       |1.5 |
|A   |2023-05-27|8       |1.1 |
|A   |2023-05-27|9       |1.1 |
|A   |2023-05-27|10      |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|11      |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|12      |1.1 |
|A   |2023-05-27|13      |1.1 |
|A   |2023-05-27|14      |1.0 |
|A   |2023-05-27|15      |1.0 |
|A   |2023-05-27|16      |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|17      |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|18      |1.6 |
|A   |2023-05-27|19      |1.6 |
|A   |2023-05-27|20      |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|21      |1.3 |
|A   |2023-05-27|22      |1.2 |
|A   |2023-05-27|23      |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|0       |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|1       |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|2       |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|3       |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|4       |1.4 |
|B   |2023-05-27|5       |1.4 |
|B   |2023-05-27|6       |1.5 |
|B   |2023-05-27|7       |1.5 |
|B   |2023-05-27|8       |1.1 |
|B   |2023-05-27|9       |1.1 |
|B   |2023-05-27|10      |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|11      |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|12      |1.1 |
|B   |2023-05-27|13      |1.1 |
|B   |2023-05-27|14      |1.0 |
|B   |2023-05-27|15      |1.0 |
|B   |2023-05-27|16      |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|17      |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|18      |1.6 |
|B   |2023-05-27|19      |1.6 |
|B   |2023-05-27|20      |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|21      |1.3 |
|B   |2023-05-27|22      |1.2 |
|B   |2023-05-27|23      |1.2 |
+----+----------+--------+----+
```